# How can the number of genes increase through evolution?

Tags: genetics, evolution

I am aware of the basics of evolutionary theory, however I don't understand how mutations can add genes over time.

Am I correct in thinking that creatures within the same species who mutate to have an additional gene in their genome would normally be infertile?  Or am I misunderstanding that?

Can someone explain the process of the creation of genetic material through evolution?  Citation to a decent academic paper or book on the matter would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Mutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation) can have all sorts of impacts on genetic architecture. A mutation can have a small impact on a genetic architecture such as

- Substitution
- Insertion
- Deletion

or can have a much bigger impact on a genetic architecture such as

- Amplification (incl. gene duplication)
- Deletions
- Chromosomal translocations
- Interstitial deletions
- Chromosomal inversions
- Chromosome duplication
- Change in ploidy number

Some of these mutations (gene duplication, Chromosome duplication, change in ploidy number) typically allows duplicating DNA segments. After duplication, the two copies of a gene can diverge through [neofunctionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neofunctionalization) or [subfunctionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfunctionalization). Have a look at [wikipedia > gene duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_duplication) to understand what biochemical processes can cause such mutations (e.g. [ectopic recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ectopic_recombination), [retrotransposition event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrotransposon), [replication slippage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_slippage)).

> Am I correct in thinking that creatures within the same species who mutate to have an additional gene in their genome would normally be infertile?

You are being mistaken. I understand the naive intuition that a change in copy number of a given gene would be extremely deleterious but in reality, living organisms seem much more resilient to such [Copy-Number Variation (CNV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-number_variation) than you would think. Of course, some CNV are associated with diseases but it is not the case of all ([McCarroll and Altshuler 2007](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v39/n7s/full/ng2080.html)).

Gene duplications are actually quite common whether in *C. elegans* ([Lipinski et al. 2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3056611/)) or in humans ([Cotton and Page 2005](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15705552)). Chromosomal duplications are also common ([Bowers et al. 2002](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v422/n6930/abs/nature01521.html)). Even whole-genome duplications (see a classical example in [Wolfe 2015](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002221)) have played major roles in the evolution of many lineages ([Whitton and Otto 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11092833)) including vertebrates ([Dehal and Boore 2005](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.0030314)).

Below is a phylogenetic tree of sequenced green plant genomes highlighting some of the main events of whole-genome duplication.

[image]

For the record, some species of [strawberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragaria) are decaploid (10 copies) ([Hummer 2012](https://www.ars.usda.gov/research/publications/publication/?seqNo115=276470)). Then there are the extremes. In [Entamoeba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entamoeba) populations, there can be variation in ploidy level among individuals ranging from diploid (2 copies) to tetracontaploid (40 copies) ([Mukherjee et al. 2008](http://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0000281))!

Comment: In flower breeding (and perhaps elsewhere) it's quite common to use chemicals to cause chromosome doubling.  As far as I can see (but maybe I only see the successes :-)), the usual result is a stronger plant with larger flowers.

Comment: Thank you, this is a comprehensive answer!  Just will take a little while to process.  Any delusions I had of being an educated person are shattered upon getting ten words into a Wikipedia article and not knowing what's going on.